# Unable to get swipe gesture work to pull out material-ui's Drawer component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using 0.16.4 material-ui and trying to get [Drawer](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/drawer) component working but I am unable to get swipe working for it. I am unable to figure out the problem myself and being a newbie I am not sure what all I can try.

```
import React from 'react';

import './App.css';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import Drawer from 'material-ui/Drawer';
import Chip from 'material-ui/Chip';

import injectTapEventPlugin from 'react-tap-event-plugin';
injectTapEventPlugin();

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      open: true
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider>
        <Drawer
          open={this.state.open}
          docked={false}
          onRequestChange={(o, r) => {
              console.log(o + " reason:" + r);
              this.setState({open: o});
          }}
          >
            <Chip>"one"</Chip>
            <Chip>"two"</Chip>
            <Chip>"three"</Chip>
        </Drawer>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

react: 15.4.0,
material-ui: 0.16.4,
react-tap-event-plugin: 2.0.1

Comment: Are you using a touch-enabled device?

Comment: Yes, I am using Android chrome browser v55 to test.

Comment: I didn't test this, but looking through source code, it looks like you might but try removing the "open={this.state.open}" on your Drawer.  It looks like it could see an explicit value there and not attach the touch events

Comment: I tried that as well but same faced same behaviour.But really I need to be able to open drawer by both sweeping and by clicking app bar, so I will have to put some props in the value for 'open'.

Comment: Does the Drawer swipe work on material-ui's documentation website? (it works for me on my Galaxy S7 Edge w/ Chrome)

Comment: Yes, the material-ui website's swipe works on the same device.

Comment: Is material-ui website's source code available somewhere that I can refer to?

Comment: Yes, it is here: https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/tree/master/docs

Comment: Found the issue. In my case body is of length zero and that's why the swipe motion event is not recognized. For a workaround I have made body to occupy complete viewport and now the drawer works fine.

Comment: I think I will add a bug on material-ui's github tracker.

Comment: @SJ - you should write down that answer and then mark it as accepted. I had the same problem, but it's easier if people don't have to search through the comments for answers.

Comment: @urban_raccoons, did that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the issue. In my case body is of length zero and that's why the swipe motion event is not recognized. For a workaround I have made body to occupy complete viewport and now the drawer works fine.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this a bit? What do mean by body with a length of zero? I'm running into the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add the

> react-tap-event-plugin package

and :

```
import injectTapEventPlugin from 'react-tap-event-plugin';
injectTapEventPlugin();
```

See: [the official docs](http://www.material-ui.com/#/get-started/installation#react-tap-event-plugin)

Comment: I have injectTapEventPlugin() since the beginning as well. But still same behaviour.